# How to apply a css rule to all the cells of the a table's column using "first-child"?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have the following table

```
 <table class = "new-hire-table">                                    
   <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" /></td>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTitle" runat="server"></td>

      <th>Position</th>
      <td><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPosition" runat="server"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I'd like to size the first column to 50px and the last column to 200px; The table has css class called **new-hire-table**. Just to test the css rules, I'm trying the apply the background color.

```
.new-hire-table tr th:first-child
{
  background-color: Blue;
}
```

But it's not working

Comment: You should close-up the spacing on the class attribute so 'class = "new-hire-table"' becomes 'class="new-hire-table"'. In your css it should be "th:first-child"

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that it's not working because you have `:firs` instead of `:first-child` in your CSS.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4UGVe/1/

```
.new-hire-table tr th:first-child{
   background-color: Blue;
    width: 50px;
}

.new-hire-table tr td:last-child{
   background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: What version of IE? IE7 and up will support `:first-child` and only IE9 and up will support `:last-child`

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say: “It's working only in FF and Chrome, not in IE” (which you should have added to the question).

Since the exact code posted works on IE when used in a conforming document, the problem is apparently caused by [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), where many “new” CSS properties are ignored.

If you are developing a new page, add `<!doctype html>` as the very first line in the HTML document and code the page by the standards. If this is an old page that relies on Quirks Mode, switching away from it may cause unpredictable problemns; in that case, consider adding a `class` attribute to the relevant cells and using a class selector instead of `:first-child`.

Comment: The page depends on a master page that seems to have been there for ever. Looking at the Master page, this is what I see: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">. Before that There is a series of page directives.

Comment: @Richard77, so what is the *first* line there? And if it contains a proper doctype string, what *other* CSS code does the page have? Your rules might be overridden by other settings.

Comment: The first line of code in the Master page is <%@ Master Language="C#" .../>. The second, the third and the forth are assembly registrations, i.e. things like <%@ register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"../>. Then you have <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"> as said earlier.

Comment: The construct `<%@ Master Language="C#" .../>` is not HTML but something used in a file from which HTML is generated. What is the first line of the HTML document that browsers actually get? (Use View Source in a browser.) Assuming that is not a doctype string in the first line, as I suspect, then Quirks Mode *is* the explanation.